# Performing an Index Rebuild from VB.NET

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to call the Index Rebuild stored procedure from a VB.NET console application, but I am getting the "User does not haver permission to perform this action" error.

I have logged onto the SQL server using the same userid as the console apps connection string, and managed to run the same stored procedure via SQL Management Studio.

While trying to get this working, I granted the userid full server admin access, but still the error occurs, but only when calling from the console app.

Code is

```
Private conPR As New SqlConnection(GetConnectionString.getconnectionstring("PR"))
Dim rebuildindexstr As String = "Exec sp_msforeachtable 'SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON; ALTER INDEX ALL ON ? REBUILD';"
Dim rebuildindexpro As New SqlCommand(rebuildindexstr, conPR)
conPR.Open()
rebuildindexpro.CommandTimeout = 0
rebuildindexpro.ExecuteNonQuery()
conPR.Close()
```

GetConnectionString just reads the required connection string from a text file
    Server=;Database=;uid=;Password=

I am using the same connection string throughout the program successfully.

Has anyone managed to perform an index rebuild from a VB.NET console app?

Comment: Try to rewrite your code without `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;` like this  `EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER INDEX ALL ON ? REBUILD`

Comment: In addition, try to execute your statement in SSMS using credentials from your connection string.

Comment: @StepUp i already tried executing from SSMS using the userid and password from connection string (well I logged onto the server using those credentials and ran the statement)

Comment: i.e. as in the Opening question "I have logged onto the SQL server using the same userid as the console apps connection string, and managed to run the same stored procedure via SQL Management Studio."

Comment: Have you tried to run like this? `Dim rebuildindexstr As String = "Exec sp_msforeachtable 'ALTER INDEX ALL ON ? REBUILD';"`

Comment: Hi @stepup Yes I just tried it and got the same error.  I think I'll try it on my local installation of SQL server and get it working on that.  It works ok with trusted credentials, but haven't tried it locally using a userid

Answer (score 0):

Try to vary this row:

```
Dim builder As SqlConnectionStringBuilder = New 
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder("Integrated Security=SSPI;")
```

OR

```
Dim builder As SqlConnectionStringBuilder = New 
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder("Integrated Security=true;")
```

What this means:

`Integrated Security = False` : User ID and Password are specified in the connection.

`Integrated Security = true` : the current Windows account credentials are used for authentication. However, be carefully it does not work in all SQL providers. It will throw an exception with `OleDb` provider.

`Integrated Security = SSPI` : this is equivalent to true, but it works with `SQL Client` and `OleDb` providers.

[Please, see connection strings at MSDN.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-syntax)

**UPDATE:**
In addition, try to set to your user the following roles such as `public` and `sysadmin`:

[image]

Comment: I changed the connection string to "trusted" instead of having userid/password and the index rebuild worked.  i'll use this as a temporary workaround I think, but won't set as an Answer just yet, in case anyone can suggest a way of getting it working with userid/password.  Maybe there is an additional setting within SQL server I am missing to allow the database to be altered by an application

Comment: @Rooq no problem, it is ok. Please, see mu updated section of an answer.

Comment: Hi Thanks @stepup.  Making the userid a sysadmin is the first thing i tried! didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @Rooq and is it `public`?